# How angularjs pipe translate internally works? does it loop through all words to get the translated word?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am working on the big application and to support multilingual i am using AngularJs pipe translation. Few places we are getting dynamic data where already translated data will come from DataBase and that data we are using to show in drop-downs.
I have added pipe translation in the drop-down list also. So does this slower the performance? 
How the angularJs pipe translate works internally? 
Does angularjs loop through the all key value pair to get translated equivalent value?

I have searched many places but didn't get how AngularJs pipe translate replaces the equivalent word internally in HTML and i didn't understand how internally it works. Whether it loop through all the object or any other method?